# Mac OS SwiftUI create a Shape with some text

Tags: string, macos, swiftui, shapes

I am writing an app that shows an image and then draw over image a coordinate grid in which i want to put some text label of the critical points of the grid. So i wrote a Shape that draws the grid and strings with the labels. The grid is drawed properly but there is no way to display the text. Here the sample code.

```
struct CoordinatesGrid: Shape {
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        let dx: Double = rect.width / 10.0
        var dy: Double = rect.height / 10.0

        let font = NSFont(name: "Courier", size: 10.0)
        let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]

        
        for i in 0 ... 10 {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: Double(i) * dx, y: 0.0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: Double(i) * dx, y: rect.maxY))

            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: Double(i) * dy))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: Double(i) * dy))

            let lbl = NSAttributedString(string: "\(Double(i) * dx)", attributes: fontAttributes as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any])
            lbl.draw(at: CGPoint(x: Double(i) * dx, y: 0.0))
            
         }
        
        return path
    }
}
```

What is the Problem ? I am a newbie in SwiftUI so probably i have done some big mistake.

I have tried in many other ways founded on web but without results.

Answer (score 0):

I think a `Shape` is only expected to return a `Path`. I am guessing that the labels do not form part of the path, so when you stroke the path, the labels are not seen.

To draw a path together with text, you can use a `Canvas`:

```swift
var body: some View {
    Canvas { ctx, size in
        var path = Path()
        let dx: Double = size.width / 10.0
        let dy: Double = size.height / 10.0
        let font = Font.custom("Courier", size: 10.0)
        for i in 0 ... 10 {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: Double(i) * dx, y: 0.0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: Double(i) * dx, y: size.height))

            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: Double(i) * dy))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: size.width, y: Double(i) * dy))

            let text = Text("\(Double(i) * dx)")
              .font(font)
            ctx.draw(text, at: CGPoint(x: Double(i) * dx, y: 10.0)) // y: 0.0 -> 10.0
        }
        ctx.stroke(path, with: .foreground)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! I have to change something due to the canvas but great solution! Thanks again.

Comment: Pleased to have been able to help. Perhaps you would be so kind as to accept the answer (by tapping the checkmark) and/or vote it up, if it helped? ;)